# Doctrine performance with a very large raw sql query

Tags: php, doctrine, mariadb

I'm dealing with an php API which use a big sql query on mariadb database (an in clause with 15000 values) and I get a low performance on the response ,even 7 seconds to get a response from the API ,the same query on mysqworkbench it's executed fast.
I'm  not sure if the great size of the query might be the cause of this low performance,the response  its not bigbecause its a count.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:  There are 15K rows in the output.  And Workbench added a `LIMIT`.  And the `LIMIT` let the query stop short.

Case 2:  If any of my assumptions for case 1 are false, please provide details, so I can concoct Case 2.  Also provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.